# Why does register $a1 always prints a 0 in Mips architecture

Tags: assembly, architecture, mips, computer-science, mips32

I was testing some mips assembly before working on an assignment and I was trying to check if characters inside a string were inside the alphabet or not. I figured a hacky way to make it work but I would prefer if someone could explain to me why my code prints out a 0 everytime.

```
.data
str1: .asciiz "allo"
str2: .asciiz "a1b2"
true: .word 1
false: .word 0
```

.text

```
main:

    la $a0, str1
    move $t0, $a0

    loop:
        lb $a0, 0($t0)           # pointer on array
        beqz $a0, end            # Checks for end of array
        blt $a0, 97, non_alpha   # Is character in the alphabet
        bgt $a0, 122, non_alpha
        addi $t0, $t0, 1         # Increment pointer
        j loop      

    end:
        li $v0, 1
        lw $a1, true      # !!! This line is the issue, why $a1 print a 0
        syscall           # When I change it to $a0 it prints out 1 as it 
                          # should

        # end program
        li $v0, 10
        syscall

non_alpha: "Did not touch this yet, ignore this"
```

Comment: Can you explain what syscall 1 does? Why do you expect it to print the value in $a1?

Comment: syscall request a service from the kernel, so in this case, li $v0 1, is the call, which means print a byte.
$a0-$a3 are procedure registers, so they store variable that are usually used as function parameters, since I had already used $a0 as the location for str1, instead of overwriting the register adress I though I should use $a1, but for some reason it kept return the value 0 when I was giving it the value 1 to return, then I tried to overwrite $a0 just to see, and it returned 1 the correct value, so I was just looking to see if someone could explain why.I'm new to mips assembly

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain how you think the syscall should know whether you want to print $a0 or $a1?

Comment: I was informed that when I call to print a byte li $v0 1, it has to be in $a0 so that why $a1 didnt work. So syscall calls the $a0-$a2, of $f12 etc.. depending on what you give to the register $v0. so reading a string with li $v0 8 (8 is string input) uses $a0 for the string and $a1 for the maximum number of character. There a bunch of different syscall that are possible with a specified registry to load

Comment: yes, so think again about that last question of prl. It's one of the main concepts of programming in assembly, when something doesn't work as expected, blame first your assumptions, and verify in debugger which one failed, then compare with the documentation of particular instruction/service. Always suspect the CPU not reading your mind and wishes, as it really does not, it always follows the definitions literally and in deterministic way, so you can count on it (pun intended).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service you are syscalling ($v0 = 1 = print_integer) only prints out the value in $a0. Any changes to $a1 will not affect the outcome as it has nothing to do with the service at all.

For more information on what each service does and what argument it uses, refer to this: https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/Help/SyscallHelp.html